# Passenger needs execute privileges for other users despite user sandboxing

Tags: passenger, passenger-nginx

I have set up a system to use NGINX and Passenger. I used RVM single-user installation for Ruby. In the NGINX file, I specified that Passenger should run as the user that owns the application directory and its subdirectories and files. Everything works, as long as I allow execution privileges for other users:

```
drwxr-x--x 15 dog_park dog_park 4096 Apr 19 01:27 dog_park/
```

I don't understand why this should be the case. The following is specified in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`:

```
        root /var/www/dog_park/public;

        # Turn on Passenger
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_user dog_park;
        passenger_ruby /home/dog_park/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/wrappers/ruby;
```

If I do not allow execution privileges to other users, I see the following in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2023/04/20 00:34:25 [crit] 1118#1118: *1 stat() "/var/www/dog_park/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: <client IP>, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "<server IP>"
```

Any ideas would be a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `nginx` (as a different user) is trying to inspect the directory.
The `stat()` in the error message is [this system call](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

From the linked docs:

> No permissions are required on the file itself, but-in the case of
> `stat()` and `lstat()` - execute (search) permission is required on all of
> the directories in `path` that lead to the file.

Comment: pidge was exactly right, I needed to add the user NGINX uses (www-data on this system) to the same group as the application's user and then it worked